# how to decode HTTP request headers and body in Python 3?

Tags: python, http, http-headers, python-3.x

i am writing an experimental asynchronous web server. i am wondering about the standard / 'best' way to decode HTTP requests in python?

basically what reading from the socket gives me is a bytes representation of the incoming request raw data; how can i turn these into standard datatypes like dictionaries, lists of values, and so on? is there a good general tutorial how to do this and what to be on the watchout for (especially regarding encodings and browser specifics)?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
import StringIO, httplib

ucode_data = unicode( your_raw_data ,"utf-8")
str = StringIO.StringIO( ucode_data )
http_header = httplib.HTTPMessage(str,0)
http_header.readheaders()

print http_header.__dict__
```

but it does not decode the request (eg, GET /index.html HTTP/1.2) - it will decode the rest for you though

Answer (score 0):

See

20.10.4. HTTPMessage Objects

An http.client.HTTPMessage instance holds the headers from an HTTP response. It is implemented using the email.message.Message class.

http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/http.client.html#httpmessage-objects

You should be able to use the `HTTPMessage` as a standalone class without invoking urllib (or whatever Python 3 equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

Don't deal with sockets; abstract! Try [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/). It's a complete HTTP library for Python 2 and 3, and it is very intuitive, although you have to download and install it. Read its [usage example](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/wiki/ExamplesPython3) for a quick introduction.

[Dive Into Python 3](http://diveintopython3.org/) includes a very good [chapter on installing and using httplib2](http://diveintopython3.org/http-web-services.html#introducing-httplib2), and why it's better than other alternatives, including the standard library; I recommend you read that.